# Foundation Zurb visibility classes

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using foundation zurb version 4. I am using foundation's visibility classes. I am using hide-for-medium-down and show-for-medium-down for displaying 2 different headers. Its working fine with ipad in both verticle as well horizontal. But when i view the site on monitor with resolution 1024*768 (ipad also has same resolution of 1024*768), both header gets displayed on monitor.

Plz help me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8ycqgLvy/ Does it work?

Comment: It works well with ipad. But issue is that for same resolution as ipad, it doesn't works on desktop monitor.

Comment: What is your desktop browser?

Comment: all browsers are installed and issue is same for all browsers. I have also checked  for compatability.

Comment: Can you show your header in jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your browser is supported. [Support list](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/support.html)
 **Notice that the IE8 has some caveats**